# Deso Google Client API (and Cloud Store API) need to be pushed to GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

GAE [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation#appengine) mentions that client api needs to be installed in the project folder. Does this need to be uploaded to GAE along with the project code or does GAE has the libraries available on their servers (in the same manner they support PIL, django, lxml, etc).

Sorry if this is a pedestrian question ? (I am also wondering why would they not bundle them into the developer SDK ? My question partly ensues from the fact that Google Cloud Storage API needs to be [downloaded](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/download) in the Python folder).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to upload the lib.

See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133) with an explanation on how to use the GAE cloud storage client with Python in GAE production and development.

Comment: Thanks - I wish I had this link earlier.. However the link does not specify that gcs library needs to bundled with your project and uploaded...